# Msp430 DATA16_I and DATA16_Z

Tags: c, msp430, iar

During my programming activities I encountered a problem with running out of RAM memory.

The message says;

```
Error[e16]: Segment DATA16_Z (size: 0x638 align: 0x1) is too long for segment definition. At least 0x44 more bytes needed. The problem occurred while  
processing the segment placement command "-Z(DATA)DATA16_I,DATA16_Z,DATA16_N=0200-_SYS_RAM_END", where at the moment of placement  
the available memory ranges were "CODE:20b-7ff" 
   Reserved ranges relevant to this placement: 
   200-7ff              DATA16_I 
Error while running Linker
```

So now I would like to have more information about DATA16_I, DATA16_Z and CSTACK on msp430 microcontroller, can anyone help me understand what these memory segments mean?

Comment: You should check the map file to see exactly which variables that were allocated where. Then you can look for improvements from there.

Comment: @Lundin this is what the .map file says to me                                                  Error[e16]: Segment CSTACK (size: 0x1c0 align: 0x1) is too long for segment definition. At least 0x2 more bytes needed. The problem occurred while processing the segment placement command "-Z(DATA)CSTACK+_STACK_SIZE#", where at the moment of placement the available memory ranges were "CODE:642-7ff"
   Reserved ranges relevant to this placement:
   200-20b              DATA16_I
   20c-641              DATA16_Z
   642-7ff              CSTACK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply read your compiler documentation  https://wwwfiles.iar.com/msp430/webic/doc/EW430_CompilerReference.pdf

for example:

[image]